# How to unzip HTTP response body by ngrep?

Tags: http, ngrep

I'm trying to capture HTTP messages between my laptop and github.com with ngrep, but some responses are not human readable because they are sent in chunked encoding and zipped, like:

`T 207.97.227.239:80 -> 192.168.0.175:41372 [AP]
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found.
Server: GitHub.com.
Date: Sun, 31 Mar 2013 09:50:25 GMT.
Content-Type: text/plain.
Transfer-Encoding: chunked.
Connection: keep-alive.
Content-Encoding: gzip.
.
25.
..........
J-./.,./.T../QH./.K........`

How can I unzip the response? Or is there better tool than ngrep to capture HTTP messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ngrep is implementation of grep for network (incoming/outgoing messages). It is not suited to capture HTTP messages. Here are two tools you can use for capturing message and viewing compressed content.

1. [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) (windows) [FAQ](https://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/faq.asp) for viewing compressed data
2. [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html) (all OS) [FAQ](http://wiki.wireshark.org/HTTP_Preferences) for viewing compressed data